# How to programmatically set the network proxy on Mac OS via node.js

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder

I am building an electron project part of which will programmatically set the system network proxy on Mac OS.

It seems there is no built-in system api(neither from nodejs nor electron) that can achieve that. As an alternative, I manage to change the proxy by revoking "networksetup" command with child_process module. But each revoke will pop up the following dialogue for the password which is quite annoying.

[image: screenshot]

```
var cp = require('child_process')
cp.exec(`networksetup -setproxyautodiscovery eth0 off`, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
cp.exec(`networksetup -setautoproxystate eth0 off`, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
cp.exec(`networksetup -setwebproxystate eth0 off`, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

The above snippet will popups three times as revoke. During development stage, I can grant root priviledge to mitigate this problem (`sudo node test.js`).

I am seeking for help how to solve this problem after package (After distributed to users, it is not possible or user friendly to ask user to run the app in terminal with root priviledge). My expectation is to ask user to grant privilidge once during app startup. No grant any more during app execution.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I am running into a similar issue trying to do something similar. Did you have any luck trying to figure out how to change the system network settings and setup a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You should give `scutil` a try. See `man scutil` for more info.

Answer (score -1):

proxy_conf_helper from ShadowsocksX-NG as an alternative.
here is the link for the reference.

[shadowsocks/ShadowsocksX-NG](https://github.com/shadowsocks/ShadowsocksX-NG/blob/develop/ShadowsocksX-NG/install_helper.sh)

Comment: Please add description as link can be inactive in future